# How to update a list adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I am creating an android application where i show a list of items and the user can select from them. I am trying to update list if items but the application is crashing all the time, no matter what code i write. the below is what i am doing

in the OnCreate method i have the below code

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, showArray);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

at the moment, showArray is an empty array and for the now the applciation works.

next, I am inserting data in showArray and I am trying to update the list adapter in another method.   i am using the below code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, showArray);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but the application crashes.  I tried to change my code to:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, showArray);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but once again no luck.

My full code is below:

```
public class Fragment_AllCommunities extends Fragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener callBack;

    // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onCommunitySelected(int position);
    }

    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private Activity activity;
    private JSONArray communities;
    private JSONObject[] commDetails;
    private String[] showArray = {""};
    private int layout = 0;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
        layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, showArray);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void updateAllCommunities(JSONObject[] commArr) throws JSONException {
        commDetails = commArr;

        showArray = new String[commDetails.length];

        for(int i=0;i<commDetails.length;i++)
        {
            showArray[i] =  commDetails[i].getString("name").toString();
        }

        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, showArray);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        try
        {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            String s = ex.getMessage();
        }

  }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.view_community_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            //getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            callBack = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        callBack.onCommunitySelected(position);

        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String a = "S";
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong pls?

thanks in advance
appreciate all responses

clive

Comment: We need the stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: add stacktrace in question.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to do it? i am a beginner in android. sry and thanks

Comment: I surrounded that code with a try catch and the stackTrace is null whilst the cause is nullpointerexception. is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your list just put this code.It will update adapter of your listview updated data.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: check wheather adapter is initialised and data is set before calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is you are calling `setListAdapter` more than once.  You should only call that as you are constructing the ListFragment.  If you want to modify your list, you have to add the data to the underlying data structure by calling the adapter's `add()` and `remove()` methods.

i.e.:

```
adapter.add(object);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Usually I create a wrapper method for adding data to the adapter.

Comment: null pointer exception all the time. i dont know why this is happening. i may try to change the whole class, maybe i make it work

Comment: @CliveCauchi What is the NPE for?  Can you give me any info on that?

Comment: @CliveCauchi I just thought of one more thing.  Try moving your code from `onCreate` to `onActivityCreated` as shown in this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/#listfragments  The problem for the NPE may be that it returns null because the Activity is not created yet.

Comment: what i can tell you is that when it goes in the first line of code, i will get a null pointer exception.  the detailMessage is null the stackTrace is null so i dont know what other information i can give you except that the first like of code is giving me the problems

Comment: @CliveCauchi if by the first line you mean `adapter.add(object)` then I think what I said in my second comment will fix that.  You might also have to edit `onCreateView` as well.  I would read up more on the Fragment lifecycle because there are some differences between them and Activity.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: we are getting to somewhere.  as you can see in my code, i have the below line of code twice:
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, showArray);
one is found in the OnCreate method whilst the other one is found in the updateAllCommunities.
the problem is that getContext() in the updateAllCommunities is null.

what can i do to call the parent activity of this fragment?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help trevor. I will look more in the lifecycle of a fragment as you told me. thanks a lot and sry for all the inconvenience that i may have caused

Comment: @CliveCauchi No problem :).  I think you are close, so just a few things to do with the Fragment itself.  Good luck.